# Matplotlib can't find documented function set_cmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.cm.set_cmap("Blues")
```

This gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\lorenz_explorer.py", line 12, in <module>
    plt.cm.set_cmap("Blues")
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cm' has no attribute 'set_cmap'
```

My matplotlib version is 3.3.1, and the function certainly exists in the documentation for 3.3.1: [Link](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap.html?highlight=matplotlib%20cm%20set_cmap#matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap)

Then am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Do I need to import `matplotlib.cm` separately or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation link you provide shows, the name of the function is `matplotlib.pyplot.set_cmap`, not `matplotlib.pyplot.cm.set_cmap`. So you can call it with `plt.set_cmap("Blues")`.

In other words, the function is not part of the `cm` library, which is somewhat counter-intuitive.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that. I spent a good thirty minutes trying to figure out if this was something to do with how I was importing it.